# Map array inside of arrays reactNative

Tags: arrays, react-native, arraylist, mapping

I get an array after console log my state that get data from Firebase. I want to know: can anyone help me to map array and get below details on ui. Thank You.

I tried below way, but app keep getting errors

```
     Array [
      Object {
        "lists": Array [
          Object {
            "lists": Array [
              Object {
                "id": "123",
                "imageUrl": "http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Pizza-Slice-PNG-Transparent-Image.png",
                "name": "Chicken Devill pizza",
                "price": 700,
                "size": "Medium",
              },
            ],
            "randomid": "32013408-0f48-4b15-80c4-eba3fc1fe295",
          },
          Object {
            "lists": Array [
              Object {
                "id": "1234",
                "imageUrl": "http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Cheese-Pizza.png",
                "name": "Cheese pork pizza",
                "price": 1500,
                "size": "Medium",
              },
            ],
            "randomid": "12a74805-4932-4397-b838-6773bc7e44b8",
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

In below code it show a error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.lists.map...')
```

```
    {this.state.lists.lists.map((current, i) => (
             
                        ))}
```

Comment: Isn't your data inappropriate to apply map on ? I removed `Array` and `Object` keyword [here](https://pastebin.com/QBRWmJc1) and it's working for me.

Comment: when I console log(this.state.lists).this is the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `list` here is an array not an Object. You can't call `lists.lists` because of this.

You will need to flatten the list or use nested map operations.

```js
export default function App() {
  const state = {
    lists: [
      {
        lists: [
          {
            id: "123",
            imageUrl:
              "http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Pizza-Slice-PNG-Transparent-Image.png",
            name: "Chicken Devill pizza",
            price: 700,
            size: "Medium"
          }
        ],
        randomid: "32013408-0f48-4b15-80c4-eba3fc1fe295"
      },
      {
        lists: [
          {
            id: "1234",
            imageUrl: "http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Cheese-Pizza.png",
            name: "Cheese pork pizza",
            price: 1500,
            size: "Medium"
          }
        ],
        randomid: "12a74805-4932-4397-b838-6773bc7e44b8"
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.lists.map((list) => {
        return list.lists.map((item) => {
          return <p>{item.id}</p>;
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can find this working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-tu-u2h8v?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

**I also want to add some thing by myself**

[image: This is data in firebase]

I done the mapping inside a mapping like this

```
{this.state.lists.map((current, i) => (
            
           <View>
           {current.map((current, i) => (
           <Fragment>
           
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card}  onPress={() => this.details(current.id)}>
                <Image style={styles.img} key={i} source={{uri: current.lists[0].imageUrl}}/>
                <Text  style={styles.txt} key={i}>{current.lists[0].name}</Text>
                <Text  style={styles.txt} key={i}>{current.lists[0].size}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.txt} key={i}>LKR.{current.lists[0].price}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
           </Fragment> 
           ))} 
           </View> 
           ))}
```